# What does it mean when angle brackets are used after an interface?

Tags: c#

My sample code has the following:

```
public class IdentityUser : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, 
    IUser, 
    IUser<string>
{
```

I understand that the IdentityUser must implement the IUser methods but can someone explain what it means:

```
IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
```

Comment: I think this might be related: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Are you sure you have `IdentityUser` both before and after `:`?

Comment: Your question title asks about angle brackets used after an interface, but in `IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>`, you're dealing with a class. In `IUser<string>`, you're dealing with an interface. (It happens to mean the same thing in both cases, so this doesn't matter much, but it's best to be precise. And it *could* be an interface -- the syntax doesn't say -- but in this case, it just so happens that it isn't.)

Comment: @hvd - Thanks, I actually thought it was an Interface but now I realize if it was then it would be called IIdenityUser. It looks rather confusing and I'm also not sure why IdentityUser would inherit from that class with the angle brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not easy to explain, but it means that the type is a generic one. You should read the relevant topic in the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx) for details or maybe the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) for an overview of the concept in general.

Answer (score 4):

The angle brackets are notation for generics. I recommend reading documentation on C# generics, such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx.

Wherever `IdentityUser` is defined is something similar to this:

```
public interface IdentityUser<A,B,C,D> {
  // ...
}
```

So if you make the following class:

```
public class MyClass : IdentityUser<string, string, string, string> {
  // ...
}
```

Then it is saying that `MyClass` implements `IdentityUser` and that the type variable `A` is `string`, the type variable `B` is `string`, and so on.